# Is there a reason why there's sometimes multiple "Bag 1" bags in particular sets?

Tags: manufacturing, packaging

When building some of the larger sets from Lego, there are sometimes cases where there's multiple large bags having the same number.  This ends up being a bit of a challenge when the build space on my table isn't that large.

I'm guessing that Lego has a good reason for doing this, is it for packing efficiency, a logical step in the build (albeit a large one), or some other consideration?

This doesn't really spoil my enjoyment (except for part-hunting time), I was just curious about the reason.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as both being "Bag 1", of course, but if you think of them as being part of "Stage 1", then there's no issue. Each stage will likely have bigger and smaller parts, and the smaller parts are easier to keep track of in their own bag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is down to purely logistic reasons, like the available plastic bag sizes, the characteristics of the different packaging pipelines (it is known that LEGO takes extreme care when packing the bags with pieces, including multiple weighings to ensure not a single part is missing - the precision required to check for the presence a small element could preclude the range necessary for bags containing many and larger pieces), the locations of the different packaging facilities, and so on.